# Using URLFetchService / URL - Google appengine for java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, httprequest

I'm using URL Fetch Java API 
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/overview.html#Fet... 
to get information from graph.facebook.com, however, i keep getting 
the error: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException 
        at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:842) 
... 
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at 
index 58: https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=... 
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message pretty much says it all: the URI you are attempting to fetch contains an illegal character at index 58. I also get the exception with your URL:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String s = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=593172238640599|e2a5e8bb8625b56358fe6219.1-530295086|zt7TYKmSF4e3WLWbF8jc7_P8MK8";

    URI uri = new URI(s);

}
```

throws:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal
>   character in query at index 58:
>   https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=593172238640599|e2a5e8bb8625b56358fe6219.1-530295086|zt7TYKmSF4e3WLWbF8jc7_P8MK8   at
>   java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2809)
>     at
>   java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:2982)
>     at
>   java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3072)
>     at
>   java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3014)
>     at java.net.URI.(URI.java:578)

The character at position 58 is the "|" character. You need to URL encode this character (and its other occurances).

Comment: The issue is that it works fine on a stand alone application, but it is not working on Google Appengine for java.

Comment: Could it be the length? Is there limitation on the length of the URL you can fitch using google appneing for java.

Comment: @user458336 - can you paste the URL?

Comment: It is working in a standard web application, and in a java application, this error appears just when deploying it the Google AppEngin4java, development environment. That's why I don't think it is related to the content of the url!

Comment: It's throwing a URISyntaxException. There's a problem with the URL, even if it works on your system (are the versions of java the same on GAE??). Paste your url.

Comment: here is the url: https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=593172238640599|e2a5e8bb8625b56358fe6219.1-530295086|zt7TYKmSF4e3WLWbF8jc7_P8MK8